# BASH/SED - Better way of removing the start and end of a string?

Tags: bash, sed

This is what I am currently using:

```
   echo /home/user/yolo/123/swag | sed 's,/home/user/,,' | sed 's,swag,,'
```

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: what is the logic here? remove first two blocks? keep just the two previous to the last? it is not clear

Comment: Change this echo `/home/user/yolo/123/swag` to `echo /home/user/yolo/420/swag`. But seriously you can join the seds together `sed 's,/home/user/,,;s,swag,,'`

Comment: Too funny :') . Oh thats usefull thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion in bash:

```
path=/home/user/yolo/123/swag
path=${path#/home/user/}       # Remove from left.
path=${path%swag}              # Remove from right.
echo "$path"
```

### Update

For an array of paths, the code is quite similar:

```
path=(/home/user/file/1/swag /home/user/file/2/swag /home/user/different/path/swag)
path=(${path[@]#/home/user/})       # Remove from left.
path=(${path[@]%swag})              # Remove from right.
echo "${path[@]}"
```

Comment: This is cool ^_^, thank you. Would you say this is a better way ?

Comment: @Infinite: It should be faster, as it doesn't start any external command.

Comment: If `path` was an array, How would you use the parameter expansion for the substituion? @choroba

Comment: If I copy and paste your code is works 100%. But this: `path=(${path[@]#/home/user/})` Does not work for my array in my actual code. Here is my array that I am trying to apply your code with `mapfile -t cfg < <(find /home/user/ -name "cfg" -type d| egrep '/home/user/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[0-9]+/csgo/cfg')` `cfgdir=(${cfg[@]#/home/user/})`
`cfgdir=(${cfg[@]%cfg})` `printf "%s \n" "${cfgdir[@]}"`

Comment: Look at above comment please @choroba

Comment: @Infinite: `cfg` and `cfgdir` are not the same variable.